# How to create summary statistics for an entire SQLite data base?

Tags: python, sqlite

Consider some SQLite database.db, with a large number of tables and columns.

Panda's [.describe()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.describe.html) produces the summary statistics that I want (see below). However, it requires reading each table in full - a problem for large data bases. Is there an (SQL or Python) alternative that is less memory hungry? Specifiying column names manually is not feasible here.

```
import pandas as pd
import sqlite3

con = sqlite3.connect("file:database.db", uri=True)
tables = pd.read_sql("SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table'", con)
columns = []
for _, row in tables.iterrows():
    col = pd.read_sql(f"PRAGMA table_info({row['name']})", con)
    col['table'] = row['name']
    stats = pd.read_sql(f"""SELECT * FROM {row['name']}""", con)
    stats = stats.describe(include='all')
    stats = stats.transpose()
    col = col.merge(stats, left_on='name', right_index=True)
    columns.append(col)
columns = pd.concat(columns)
```

Comment: What sort of statistics do you want? What is `pd` in your code? Generally you'd do the stats in SQL, not by slurping all the data into Python.

Comment: The SQL `GROUP BY` clause and `COUNT` function are great for summarizing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps a little over the top but you could use TRIGGERS to maintain statistics and eliminate the need for full table scans. There will obviously be some overhead for maintaining the statistics but the overheads are distributed over time.

Perhaps consider the following demo (in SQL) where there are two  main tables tablea and tablex (could be any number of tables). Another table called statistic which will be used to dynamically store statistics.

For each main table 3 triggers are created 1 for when a row is inserted, one for when a row is updated and one for when a row is deleted. So 6 triggers in all for the 2 main tables.

The statistic tables has 5 columns

1. **tablename** which is the primary key and holds the name is the table the row stores statistics about
2. **row_count** for the number of rows (in theory)

   1. The insert trigger for the respective table increments the row_count
   2. The delete trigger decrements the row_count
3. **insert_count**

   1. The insert trigger increments the insert_count
4. **update_count**

   1. the update trigger  increments the update_count
5. **delete_count**

   1. the delete trigger increments the delete_count

All of the triggers first try to insert the respective row for the table with all values using the default of 0. As the tablename is the primary key the INSERT OR IGNORE ensures that the row is only added the once (unless the row is deleted (effectively resetting the stats for the table))

The demo includes some insertions, deletions and updates and finally extraction of the statistics:-

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tablea;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tablex;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS statistic;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS statistic (
    tablename TEXT PRIMARY KEY, 
    row_count INTEGER DEFAULT 0, 
    insert_count INTEGER DEFAULT 0, 
    update_count INTEGER DEFAULT 0, 
    delete_count INTEGER DEFAULT 0
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tablea (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, data1 TEXT);
CREATE TRIGGER IF NOT EXISTS tablea_after_ins AFTER INSERT ON tablea
    BEGIN
        INSERT OR IGNORE INTO statistic (tablename) VALUES('tablea');
        UPDATE statistic SET row_count = row_count +1, insert_count = insert_count + 1 WHERE tablename = 'tablea';
    END
;
CREATE TRIGGER IF NOT EXISTS tablea_after_update AFTER UPDATE ON tablea
    BEGIN
        INSERT OR IGNORE INTO statistic (tablename) VALUES('tablea');
        UPDATE statistic SET update_count = update_count + 1 WHERE tablename = 'tablea';
    END
;
CREATE TRIGGER IF NOT EXISTS tablea_after_delete AFTER DELETE ON tablea
    BEGIN
        INSERT OR IGNORE INTO statistic (tablename) VALUES('tablea');
        UPDATE statistic SET row_count = row_count -1, delete_count = delete_count + 1 WHERE tablename = 'tablea';
    END
;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tablex (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, data1 TEXT);
CREATE TRIGGER IF NOT EXISTS tablex_after_ins AFTER INSERT ON tablex
    BEGIN
        INSERT OR IGNORE INTO statistic (tablename) VALUES('tablex');
        UPDATE statistic SET row_count = row_count +1, insert_count = insert_count + 1 WHERE tablename = 'tablex';
    END
;
CREATE TRIGGER IF NOT EXISTS tablex_after_update AFTER UPDATE ON tablex
    BEGIN
        INSERT OR IGNORE INTO statistic (tablename) VALUES('tablex');
        UPDATE statistic SET update_count = update_count + 1 WHERE tablename = 'tablex';
    END
;
CREATE TRIGGER IF NOT EXISTS tablea_after_delete AFTER DELETE ON tablea
    BEGIN
        INSERT OR IGNORE INTO statistic (tablename) VALUES('tablex');
        UPDATE statistic SET row_count = row_count -1, delete_count = delete_count + 1 WHERE tablename = 'tablex';
    END
;

INSERT INTO tablea (data1) VALUES('a');
INSERT INTO tablea (data1) VALUES('b'),('c'),('d'),('z');
DELETE FROM tablea WHERE data1 LIKE 'z';
UPDATE tablea set data1 = 'letter_'||data1;
DELETE FROM tablea WHERE data1 LIKE '%_c';

INSERT OR IGNORE INTO tablex (data1) VALUES
    ('1a'),('2a'),('3a'),('4a'),('5a')
    ,('1b'),('2b'),('3b'),('4b'),('5b')
    ,('1c'),('2c'),('3c'),('4c'),('5c')
    ,('1d'),('2d'),('3d'),('4d'),('5d')
;

SELECT * FROM statistic;
/* Cleanup the demo environment */
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tablea;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tablex;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS statistic;
```

When run the result is :-

[image]

- note that the mass insert into tablex records all 20 rows added (i.e the trigger is triggered for every insert and that the triggering is part of the transaction)